# R: pass a character string from command line as vector components

Tags: r, vector, command-line-arguments

I have a data frame called `counts` like this:

```
    Mark    Helen
A     12        1
B      3       56
C      8        9
```

I use different functions that assign a group index to each column of the data frame:

```
ind <- factor(c("MALE","FEMALE"))
result <- function(counts,ind)
```

Instead of editing manually the `ind <- factor(c("MALE","FEMALE"))` command in my R script every time I have a different data frame, to gain some time I am trying to pass the vector components from the command line.

Command line I am using:

```
R -f my_script.R --args "MALE","FEMALE"
```

where `my_script.R` is:

```
arg <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

ind <- factor(c(unlist(strsplit(path[1],","))))
result <- function(counts,ind)
```

Although I get the same `ind` values whether I edit the script manually or pass the argument from the command line:

```
> ind
[1] MALE FEMALE
Levels: MALE FEMALE
> ind[1]
[1] MALE
Levels: MALE FEMALE
> ind[2]
[1] FEMALE
Levels: MALE FEMALE

> length(ind)
[1] 2
> ncol(counts)
[1] 2
```

I get this error only when I use the argument from the command line:

```
> result <- function(counts,ind)
 length(ind) == ncol(counts) is not TRUE
```

Any idea, how could I pass the string argument properly?

Comment: `ind <- factor(c(unlist(strsplit(path[1],","))))` It looks like you should have used `arg[1]` not `path[1]`?